# cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode'

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, tree, treeview

Dunno why getting this stupid or more like sense less error, Normally we add strings to a treeNode then why not in this code,

```
groupNode.ChildNodes.Add(UserPair.Value);
```

(why not ?)

```
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();

        try
        {
            int Index = 0;
            TreeView tree = new TreeView();
            TreeNode groupNode; 
            Dictionary<int, string> GroupList = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            Dictionary<int, string> UserList = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            List<string> IndividualUserList = new List<string>();

            foreach (SPUser user in SPContext.Current.Web.Users)
            {
                string groupName = FormatUserLogin(user.Name);

                if (groupName != "" && groupName != "System Account")
                    IndividualUserList.Add(groupName);
                else if (user.IsDomainGroup && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupName) && 
                    Directory.DoesGroupExist(groupName))
                {
                    Index++;
                    GroupList.Add(Index, groupName);
                    List<ADUser> adUsers = Directory.GetUsersFromGroup(groupName);

                    foreach (ADUser member in adUsers)
                    {
                        if (member != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(member.DisplayName))
                            UserList.Add(Index, member.DisplayName);
                    }
                }
            }

            IndividualUserList.Sort();

            foreach (string Item in IndividualUserList)
            {
                groupNode = new TreeNode(Item);
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> GroupPair in GroupList)
            {
                groupNode = new TreeNode(GroupPair.Value);
                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> UserPair in UserList)
                {
                    if (UserPair.Key == GroupPair.Key)
                        groupNode.ChildNodes.Add(UserPair.Value);
                }
            }

            tree.Nodes.Add(groupNode);

            this.Controls.Add(tree);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //loggingit
        }
    }
```

I thought treeNodes are there to add string values to them, also please let me know if there is any logical mistake or bug in my code.

Cheers

**Answer**

```
if (UserPair.Key == GroupPair.Key)
                    {
                        TreeNode userNode = new TreeNode(UserPair.Value);
                        groupNode.ChildNodes.Add(userNode);
                    }
```

Comment: shouldn't that be UserPair.Value.ToString();

Comment: @Sam1: No, it's a `KeyValuePair<int, string>`, so the `Value` property is already of type `string`.

Comment: @user1362605 just trying to help dude take it easy

Comment: I was trying to add a string as childnode, which makes me look stupid now -_-

Comment: @user1362605: Please don't be rude to users like this. Telling someone not to comment when you've asserted that a perfectly sensible (and easily investigated) error is "stupid or more like senseless" really doesn't look good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`groupNode.ChildNodes` is a [TreeNodeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.childnodes.aspx).  You can only add objects of type `TreeNode` to the collection.  Change this line:

```
groupNode.ChildNodes.Add(UserPair.Value);
```

to:

```
groupNode.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(UserPair.Value));
```

Comment: when I tried to change that , I am getting this error, "Error 1 Use of unassigned local variable 'groupNode"

Comment: Initialize your groupNode variable when you first declare it (null or an empty node, depending on your requirements).

Comment: I was facing same issue like tree.Nodes.Add(node); . I changed it to tree.Nodes.Add(node.ToString()); and voila!!!!